# textColorPrimary is to colorOnBackground/colorOnSurface while textColorSecondary is to?

Tags: android, material-components-android, theming

So I've been following the guidelines mentioned here 
 https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color/ for Color Theming my application.

Previously before this, there was an attribute called `textColorPrimary` and `textColorSecondary`. However now according to the document, you should use `colorOnBackground` and `colorOnSurface` for typography.

For the most part, `textColorPrimary` can simply be mapped to `colorOnBackground` and/or `colorOnSurface` depending on the component where the text is rendered on top of. My problem is with the `textColorSecondary` or the grey text (like subtitles). What is the correct way to map it to the new attributes provided in the material components document?